# WildFly 8.2 does not start project while Jboss 7.1 do

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jboss, wildfly-8

My project originally developed under Jboss but if start it on WildFly there is only message in browser: "Not Found" and any errors.
Is there something what I missed?

web.xml mapping

```
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

index.jsp

```
<jsp:forward page="./faces/index.xhtml" />
```

So it works on Jboss but does't on WildFly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in jsp. Have no idea why it does't work with WildFly, but setting `welcome-file` in web.xml like `faces/index.xhtml` solved issue.